# How to change active bootstrap tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to change the active tab and failed to use the javascript onclick element correctly. Here's the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="text-align: left;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class=“tab-content">

<div id="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
Text

<a href="#second" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="CHANGE ACTIVE TAB TO SECOND" data-toggle="tab">Second</a>

<a href="#third" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="CHANGE ACTIVE TAB TO THIRD" data-toggle="tab">Third</a>

</div>


<div id="second" class="tab-pane fade in">
Text
</div>


<div id="third" class="tab-pane fade in">
Text
</div>


</div>
```

How could I be able to use the buttons to change the active tab to their associated id? Please advise.

Have a great day!

Comment: Your quotes are a bit strange. Use the standard `"`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can trigger click on tab you want when click on your buttons

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="text-align: left;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab" id="first_tab">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab" id="second_tab">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third" data-toggle="tab" id="third_tab">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">        
    <div id="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        Text        
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="$('#second_tab').trigger('click')">Second</a>        
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="$('#third_tab').trigger('click')">Third</a>        
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oyb8smdg/)

Comment: Genius! Saved me a lot of time and effort!

Comment: no longer working in boostrap5, now using .tab('show') per @jacobGoh

Comment: Oh my. MANY hours spent - and to find ONE LINE of code is the resolution - sigh...

Answer (score 82):

you may also use `.tab('show')` for more flexibility

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ALELNr

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="menu3()">go to menu 3</button>
```

javascript:

```
function menu3(){
  $('[href="#menu3"]').tab('show');
}
```

Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Not sure why, but `tab('show')` only changes my active tab, not the detail pane as well.

Comment: As for now (Feb 2020) still the accepted solution should be Aya Salama's https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461471/2979069

tab('show') does not work always

Answer (score 3):

Here is your js

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    $('#myTab a[href=#tabs3-2k_tab2]').tab('show')
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: When using attribute queries, it's usually a good idea to quote the attribute like `$('#myTab a[href="#tabs3-2k_tab2"]')` - this prevents any special characters from causing the selector to error or throw a warning.

Comment: This gives an error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #ToETabs a[href=#property_tab]

Answer (score 3):

Updated on bootstrap5

```
<div class="tab-control" data-role="tab-control">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="frames">
        <div class="frame" id="tab1">
            //Content tab 1
        </div>
        <div class="frame" id="tab2">
            //Content tab 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



var someTabTriggerEl = document.querySelector('#tab1');
    var tab = new bootstrap.Tab(someTabTriggerEl);
    tab.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the data attribute approach, is a clean solution and separate View from Controller code

```
<a href="#btn-next"data-next="#tab1" class="btn btn-primary">go to menu 1</a>
<a href="#btn-next"data-next="#tab2" class="btn btn-primary">go to menu 2</a>
```

javascript:

```
$('a[href="#btn-next"]').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var tab = $(this).data('next'); 
  $(tab).tab('show');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working example**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
});

$('button').addClass('btn-primary').text('Switch to Orange Tab');
$('button').click(function(){
      $('#tabs a[href=#orange]').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <center><h6>Switching Among the Tabs</h6></center>
 <div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a>  </li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
            <button>Blue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
            <button>Blue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
            <button>Blue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
            <button>Blue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
            <button>Blue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and works.

```
function do_something () {

   $('#profile-tab').click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Scala, refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ngx_bootstrap/ngx_bootstrap_tabs.htm,
namely:

```
    <tabset>
       <tab heading="View">
       <tab heading="Configuration" (selectTab)="showConfig()==true" [active]="showConfig()">`  
    </tabset>
```

(you need both selectTab and active)...

The click() solutions suggested by others are working, but are generating exception "Expression has changed after it was checked." so it seams a bad habit, even if the exception is not raised in production mode.

```
    //bad code!
    ngAfterViewInit()  {
      if (thisCreation){ 
        document.getElementById("tabConfig-link").click();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue you can get the button or link by id and call the "click()" event, like so:

```
ShowResults: function () {
    let resultsTab = document.getElementById("pills-results-tab");

    //show the results tab:
    resultsTab.click();
},
```

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
     <button class="nav-link" id="pills-results-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-results" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-results" aria-selected="false">Results</button>
</li>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-results" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-results-tab">
     <h4>Results:</h4>
     <p>This is what will show</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommended this codes.

```
<div class="tab-control" data-role="tab-control">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="frames">
        <div class="frame" id="tab1">
            //Content tab 1
        </div>
        <div class="frame" id="tab2">
            //Content tab 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add effects that you want in class attribute.