# Change Bootstrap 5 active tab using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, tabs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to change an active tab when a button is clicked from inside another tab. All the examples I have found are tabs with anchor tags, none with buttons. Am I able to achieve this without changing from buttons to anchor tags? I have tried to apply the code I see for the anchor tags but that has not been successful. When I click view more, id like to switch to the referral tab

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs innerTab" id="allTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="all-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#all" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="all" aria-selected="true">All</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="referral-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#referral" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="referral" aria-selected="false">Ref</button>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profit-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profit" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profit" aria-selected="false">Pro</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="merchandise-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#merchandise" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="merchandise" aria-selected="false">Merch</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="withdrawal-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#withdrawal" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="withdrawal" aria-selected="false">History</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="walletContent">
  <div class="tab-pane show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
    <div class="row goal-meter mb-4 g-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card card-transparent">
          <div>
            <a class="v-link-green d-inline-block float-end mt-3 me-3 view-more">View
                                                            more</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="progress prog-green" data-value='46'>
              <span class="progress-left">
                                                                <span class="progress-bar"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="progress-right">
                                                                <span class="progress-bar"></span>
              </span>
              <div class="progress-value">46%</div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-title">Referral
              <p class="highlight-green fig">$120,000.00</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="referral" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="referral-tab">
    Ref
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profit" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profit-tab">
    Profit
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="merchandise" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="merchandise-tab">
    Merch
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="withdrawal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="withdrawal-tab">
    With
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461076/how-to-change-active-bootstrap-tab-with-javascript

Comment: This uses anchor tags instead of buttons as I would have mentioned @AlfredoRahnLinde

Comment: Bootstrap 5 doesn't use jQuery, nor does it offer jQuery functions. Use plain JavaScript per [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to the button with id "referral-tab" and when the **View more** link is clicked, use bootrap's api to show it.

1. Define the code to show the specific tab:

```js
var triggerEl = document.getElementById('referral-tab')
var tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl)
  
function activateReferralsTab() {
  bootstrap.Tab.getInstance(triggerEl).show() // Select tab by name
}
```

2. Attach the **activateReferralsTab()** function to the **View more** link **onclick** handler:

```html
<a
  class="v-link-green d-inline-block float-end mt-3 me-3 view-more"
  onclick="activateReferralsTab()">
  View more
</a>
```

What follows is a running example.

```js
var triggerEl = document.getElementById('referral-tab')
var tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl)
  
function activateReferralsTab() {
  bootstrap.Tab.getInstance(triggerEl).show() // Select tab by name
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs innerTab" id="allTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="all-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#all" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="all" aria-selected="true">All</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="referral-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#referral" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="referral" aria-selected="false">Ref</button>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profit-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profit" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profit" aria-selected="false">Pro</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="merchandise-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#merchandise" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="merchandise" aria-selected="false">Merch</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="withdrawal-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#withdrawal" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="withdrawal" aria-selected="false">History</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="walletContent">
  <div class="tab-pane show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
    <div class="row goal-meter mb-4 g-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card card-transparent">
          <div>
            <a class="v-link-green d-inline-block float-end mt-3 me-3 view-more" onclick="activateReferralsTab()">View more</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="progress prog-green" data-value='46'>
              <span class="progress-left">
                                                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="progress-right">
                                                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
              </span>
              <div class="progress-value">46%</div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-title">Referral
              <p class="highlight-green fig">$120,000.00</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="referral" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="referral-tab">
    Ref
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profit" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profit-tab">
    Profit
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="merchandise" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="merchandise-tab">
    Merch
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="withdrawal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="withdrawal-tab">
    With
  </div>
</div>`enter code here`
```