# Is it possible after click on an IMG to go to a specific tab in bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible after click on an IMG to go to a specific tab in bootstrap 5?
Unfortunately a href in an IMG code doesn't work in this case.

I wanna go to About Me tab after clicking on a **first** img
I wanna go to Projects tab after clicking on a **second** img
I wanna go to Contact tab after clicking on a **third** img

Please find my code below and on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/84zyvu0t/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#aboutMe" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#projects" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 1 - About Me -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="aboutMe">
            <p>Hi, my name is Robert</p>
        </div>

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 2 - Projects -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="projects">
            <p>This is a projects tab</p>
        </div>

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 3 - Contact -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
            <p>Reach out to me</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#aboutMe"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200/300" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#projects"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/200/300" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#contact"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/29/200/300" alt=""></a>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript that shows a click event bound to the image?  And your attempt to activate a "tab" as a result?  (You could start by researching how to focus on a Bootstrap "tab", and how to bind a click event to an image).  And then explain at what point in your code you aren't getting the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this link (Jacob Goh's solution)

[How to change active bootstrap tab with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461076/how-to-change-active-bootstrap-tab-with-javascript)

> you may also use .tab('show') for more flexibility
>
> https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ALELNr
>
> go to menu
> 3 javascript:
>
> function menu3(){   $('[href="#menu3"]').tab('show'); } Bootstrap
> documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

**BUT** I had to turn my imgs to buttons (so to speak) so I'm not even sure if that'll work in the future and if there are any consequences using them this way...

**SOLUTION**

```js
function aboutMeTab() {
    $('[href="#aboutMe"]').tab('show');
}

function projectsTab() {
    $('[href="#projects"]').tab('show');
}

function contactTab() {
    $('[href="#contact"]').tab('show');
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#aboutMe" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#projects" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menuItems">
                <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 1 - About Me -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="aboutMe">
            <p>Hi, my name is Robert</p>
        </div>

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 2 - Projects -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="projects">
            <p>This is a projects tab</p>
        </div>

        <!-- TAB NUMBER 3 - Contact -->

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
            <p>Reach out to me</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#aboutMe">
        <button class="btn btn-primary przycisk" onclick="aboutMeTab()">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200/300" alt="">
        </button>
    </a>
    
        <a href="#projects">
        <button class="btn btn-primary przycisk" onclick="projectsTab()">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/200/300" alt="">
        </button>
    </a>
    
        <a href="#contact">
        <button class="btn btn-primary przycisk" onclick="contactTab()">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/29/200/300" alt="">
        </button>
    </a>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work. Please put your solution here using the editor. You can easily create Bootstrap demos just as you do at JSFiddle. Be sure to remove all obsolete information from your answer. It doesn't need to show your historical process.